# HTML Table not displaying properly

Tags: html, html-table

Hey guys I was creating this table table recently in HTML.
image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbdFS.jpg
The table (shown in image) created perfectly but a weird blank row was created (marked red in image). When I tried to delete that code the entire cells below the QUESTIONS row gets shifted (image link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/7awt3.jpg).
How do I remove that blank cell after MEN cell?

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      
    <body>
        <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">QUESTIONAIRE RESULTS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">QUESTIONS</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">WOMEN</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">MEN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>NO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td>42%</td>
            <td>58%</td>
            <td>61%</td>
            <td>39%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 2</td>
            <td>53%</td>
            <td>47%</td>
            <td>69%</td>
            <td>31%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 3</td>
            <td>26%</td>
            <td>74%</td>
            <td>51%</td>
            <td>49%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 4</td>
            <td>40%</td>
            <td>60%</td>
            <td>60%</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use jsfiddle instead of previewing output in image. check http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the :

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

so your final code will be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      
    <body>
        <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">QUESTIONAIRE RESULTS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">QUESTIONS</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">WOMEN</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">MEN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>NO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td>42%</td>
            <td>58%</td>
            <td>61%</td>
            <td>39%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 2</td>
            <td>53%</td>
            <td>47%</td>
            <td>69%</td>
            <td>31%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 3</td>
            <td>26%</td>
            <td>74%</td>
            <td>51%</td>
            <td>49%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 4</td>
            <td>40%</td>
            <td>60%</td>
            <td>60%</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/3q6n9v7k/

Answer (score 0):

A more correct answer would be the changing the `rowspan` and `colspan`.

Instead of

```
 <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">QUESTIONS</td> //
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">WOMEN</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">MEN</td>
 </tr>
```

Do this

```
 <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">QUESTIONS</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">WOMEN</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">MEN</td>             
 </tr>
```

Also remove :

```
 <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

check out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitatcs/vf95vg2w/)